# Trouble with inline inputs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble finding a reliable way to make two inputs appear inline in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Gt8g/10/):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Things</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#/things/new">Add Thing</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: inputs here should be adjacent, right-aligned, and vertically-aligned with the H3 on the left.]

When I set the class of the divs around the inputs to be form-group (as it should be), the search input stops looking right.

I can sort of fix it by putting the inputs in different grid columns, but then they don't align together properly. I want them to be next to each other and right-aligned, and I want them to be vertically-aligned with the h3 tag on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/IRUciJe/1/**

**WITH RESPONSIVE TABLE: http://jsbin.com/IRUciJe/2/edit**

[image: input group form inline example]}

```
<div class="row" role="search-row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
   <h3>Things</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
   <form class="form-inline float-right" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

     <!-- <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search + Enter" />-->

     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.form-group--> 

    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Add Thing</a>
  </form>
  </div>
  <!--/.col-md-8-->

 </div>
 <!--/.row role=search-row-->
```

CSS

```
body { padding-top: 80px; }
hr.empty {margin:0 0 3% 0;border:0;}
div[role=search-row] h3 {margin:0 0 2%}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
div[role=search-row]  .float-right {float:right}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christina, but I'm having trouble understanding what you've done here. The controls still seem to be on separate lines. You'll note that in my original post, "this example" is a link to my jsfiddle of the problem. Can you please edit that?

Comment: I've incorporated your suggestion here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cayblood/9Gt8g/13/

However, this doesn't really solve the issue because, as you'll notice, the form items still have a pretty ugly gap between them (seems too big to me) and they also don't line up vertically with the h3 on the left. I would expect not to have to tweak such things, that bootstrap elements on the same row would be vertically aligned by default, as they were in bootstrap 2. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll also notice that the button isn't right-aligned with the table below it. Any idea on how to fix that? --Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Bootstrap 2 version of this? Bootply automatically converts 2 to 3 with decent results. Paste the 2 version to me in a link. The gap between columns is being complained about as is the vertical rhythm, which is the reason why the h3 doesn't line up as it has a top margin. I have a resets file I'm using until they work this out.

Comment: So, here is a slightly improved version of my bs3 version: http://jsfiddle.net/cayblood/9Gt8g/16/
And here is a 2.3.2 version: http://jsfiddle.net/cayblood/9Gt8g/22/
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I got it. Will post in 10 min.

Comment: Okay, look at the demo link and see some classes that were wrong in mine and yours. http://jsbin.com/IRUciJe/1 (icons don't show up on jsbnin). There's new classes to handle things on same line and you need the form-inline class and a few other tweaks as there's vertical spacing issues being discussed in the TBS forum.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42668/discussion-between-christina-arasmo-beymer-and-carl-youngblood)